# How does TFS know about nuget?

Tags: tfs, nuget

From [this article](http://blog.nuget.org/20120518/package-restore-and-consent.html) -

*"However, there are cases where it’s not actually a person who’s doing the building and who therefore can’t provide consent this way. (And where Visual Studio isn’t even installed.) The prototypical example is a build server. In that case, NuGet will also look for an environment variable called EnableNuGetPackageRestore. To enable package restore for scenarios where the Visual Studio option is not practical, set this variable to true."*

How does TFS even know how to call nuget?  Do I install the nuget exe?

Comment: Is there a specific issue that you're trying to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does TFS even know how to call nuget? Do I install the nuget exe?

No, you should enable package restore for the solution which can be done from the context menu for the solution file in the solution explorer. This will add a folder named `.nuget` to your solution and in this folder you will find `NuGet.exe`.

[image: NuGet solution folder]

If you add the solution to source control and build it on a build server the `NuGet.exe` executable will be used by the NuGet msbuild targets to restore packages from NuGet as part of the build.

So you do not need to install NuGet on the build server - it becomes part of your project and is placed under version control.

Comment: I do not have this folder

Comment: @user210757: _"you should enable package restore for the solution __which can be done from the context menu for the solution file in the solution Explorer___"

Comment: Yes, I am just reading about this (actually arguments against it) http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html

Comment: @user210757: The blog entry does not seem to take build servers into account and your question was specifically about how to restore NuGet packages on a build server. As is stated in the blog entry: _"when building from the command line, you need to run 'nuget restore' yourself before msbuild."_ So I guess you could modify you build workflow to run `nuget restore` before running msbuild instead of enabling NuGet package restore for the solution.

Comment: I hear you - I just want to do this the right way so if the .nuget/ folder is being phased out I would try the blog's way. But, I can't really find any reason explaining why the automatic package restore is better

Answer (score 3):

As you've stated in a comment, "Enable NuGet Package Restore" is no longer the recommended method for accomplishing this. The [NuGet docs](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore) explain it best. Basically, because that method is integrated into MSBuild, packages that extend the build will be downloaded too late. While I'm not sure what packages do this currently it appears that there are big plans for the future of NuGet (the new ASP.NET vNext custom CLR implementation is one example of where it's headed).

The good news is that the alternative is really easy to set up. If you're in VS, you literally do nothing (unless you've disabled the automatic package restore in the past). If you have a build server you just have to make some small changes to your .proj file. If you're not familiar with MSBuild it may seem challenging but it's really quite simple. The secret is this chunk of code:

```
<Target Name="RestorePackages">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(ToolsHome)NuGet\NuGet.exe&quot; restore &quot;%(Solution.Identity)&quot;" />
</Target>
```

Again, the details are in the docs  ([this one](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore-with-team-build) specifically). If you have any questions don't be afraid to reach out: the SO community is here to help!

Comment: I have targets "MvcBuildViews" and "EnsuerBclBuildImported" would you recommend making those dependent on the RestorePackages, or use the "BeforeBuild" or "AfterBuild" targets my proj file recommends?

Comment: A few more details would help. How many solutions do you have and what kind of build are you using? Do you have a dedicated msbuild proj file or is it just your project files?

Comment: One sln file and I was changing the actual .csproj file, and it is the only project file, which is just an MVC web app. A dedicated build would be nice if straight forward, however I didn't really want to get into learning msbuild

Comment: You can just put the package restore in the BeforeBuild. If you're not using a build server then you don't even need to worry about it. Are you using a build server?

Comment: %(Solution.Identity) was blank, I had to use: $(SolutionDir)\$(SolutionFileName). Also I wonder if I need conditions around this so it only happens on a build and not every VS compile, since it just works in VS; does that mean it's running twice

Comment: It may run twice, but it shouldn't be a serious issue: it will only restore packages that are missing. That said, if you plan on having more than one solution, this would be a good opportunity to create an MSBuild file.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your solutions to restore NuGet packages, and then on the build server with the build account, open vs and set Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build in Visual Studio. Your builds should restore packages ok.